# Duplicate account/email

Tags: support, status-completed, login, user-accounts, duplicate-user

I'm posting this question from the account I'm logged into using my email. However, somehow at some point the account duplicated, or how do I call this. [https://stackexchange.com/users/[id-removed]/[username-removed]](https://stackexchange.com/users/%5Bid-removed%5D/%5Busername-removed%5D) has the same email (confirmed by gravatar link), but I can't log into it. I could live with this situation, but I want to remove my full name from there.

Comment: You should use the [contact form](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to contact the Stack Exchange team directly. Select the "I need to merge user profiles" option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done - you had a user on Android that I merged with your main account.

All should now be well.